# Am i missing a split function that can split the data line by line?

Tags: javascript, function, split, data-cleaning, ppm

```
**The PPM file given:**


   P3
   3x4-image.ppm
   3 4
   255
   0 0 0 255 255 255 0 0 0
   255 255 255 0 0 0 255 255 255
   0 0 0 255 255 255 0 0 0
   255 255 255 0 0 0 255 255 255
```

**Trying to:**
Create a function cleanData(fileContents) that returns an array with the contents of thePPM file. The function simply takes the string and splits the data
into a one-dimensional array. Use the space character as the delimiter when splitting the
data up into an array. Any empty values in the array must be removed.

```
**The result should be:** 
   [
  'P3'
  '3 4'
  '255'
  '0 0 0 255 255 255 0 0 0'
  '255 255 255 0 0 0 255 255 255'
  '0 0 0 255 255 255 0 0 0'
  '255 255 255 0 0 0 255 255 255'
   ]

**The code I have:**
    function cleanData(fileContents) {
    let data = fileContents.split(/\r\n|\n/);
    data = data.filter(line => line.trim().substring(0,1) !== '#').join(' ');
    data = data.split(/\s/);
    data = data.filter(elt => elt.trim() !== '');
    return data
    }

**The answer I am getting:**
   [
  'P3', '3',   '4',   '255', '0', '0',
  '0',  '255', '255', '255', '0', '0',
  '0',  '255', '255', '255', '0', '0',
  '0',  '255', '255', '255', '0', '0',
  '0',  '255', '255', '255', '0', '0',
  '0',  '255', '255', '255', '0', '0',
  '0',  '255', '255', '255'
   ]
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

When you do `data = data.filter(line => line.trim().substring(0,1) !== '#').join(' ');` you merge all the strings into one, adding by separator a simple space, and when you do `data = data.split(/\s/);` you're splitting using all the spaces, the one added in previous step and the one already present in your original strings. I think you should avoid second split:

```js
function cleanData(fileContents) {
    let data = fileContents.split(/\r\n|\n/);
    data = data.filter(line => line.trim().substring(0,1) !== '#');
    data = data.filter(elt => elt.trim() !== '');
    return data;
}
```

or also better:

```js
function cleanData(fileContents) {
    return fileContents.split(/\r\n|\n/)
        .filter(line => line.trim() && line.trim().substring(0,1) !== '#');
}
```